# How to set an id in local storage of parent site from the child site using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've two sites like abc.com and xyz.com. By using window popup, i am opening xyz as child site from abc.com(parent site). I want to set an id in local storage of parent site from the child site. How it is possible by using javascript?

Comment: localStorage doesn't work with different domains. You could use an iFrame with [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) for this.

Comment: Can you explain more, what you expect to store in the local storage?

Comment: i want to store user token in abc.com from xyz.com . Due to cross domain issue, i couldn't set it.

Comment: What if we use cookie... ?

Comment: Cookie doesnot work in cross domain

Comment: A cookie could work if the two domains are both subdomains of the same domain, ex. if one is a.example.com and the other is b.example.com, you could set the cookie on .example.com and it would be available to both. But it isn't possible for the domains in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to do that directly. If you control both domains, then you might be able to communicate between them with a different mechanism.

If xyz has a handle to the abc `Window` object (for example from `window.parent`), then you can use [`Window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to send the data you want to abc, and then in the abc site, store it in localStorage.

If postMessage doesn't work, you could send an HTTP request to an endpoint on abc.com that somehow sends data down to the abc.com (for example using a websocket) to tell it to store the localStorage.

If you don't control abc.com, then it simply isn't possible, because setting the localStorage on another domain would be a security vulnerability.

Comment: Window.postMessage again shows cross origin problem

Answer (score -1):

You can try Javascript localstorage

**Example**

```
localStorage.setItem('popState','shown');

var popState=localStorage.getItem('popState');

if(popState=='shown'){
    localStorage.removeItem("popState");
}
```

Try modifying the code accordingly.

Comment: The concern is about working localStorage for multiple domains, which is not possible.